# To implement the checkbox in custom listview

Tags: android, checkbox, custom-lists

I have written the code to show the list of contents from the database and also able to click on the perticular item and to get the name of the item which was clicked.But I want to implement the checkbox and to get the value of the item which is checked,How to do it.I have taken the custom list row.xml

```
private void displayListView() {
        final Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllRecords();
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                RecordsDbAdapter.KEY_NAME,
                RecordsDbAdapter.KEY_BIRTHDAY,

        };
        int[] to = new int[] {
                R.id.name,
                R.id.birthdate,
        };
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.row,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)) .getText().toString();
                BirtDate = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.birthdate)) .getText().toString();
                Log.d("*************", name);
                Info=name+ " " +BirtDate+ " "+ "years";
                edt.setText(Info,TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                topaste=edt.getText().toString();

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Check => [select multi item from listview](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=android+select+multi+item+from+listview)

Answer (score 0):

Add below Code into your custom adapter class, it will solve your problem.

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mName.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
```